# On matplotlib logarithmic axes labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

Dear matplotlib community,

I have a very quick question regarding logarithmic axis labelling that I'm sure one of you could answer at the drop of a hat.

Essentially I have a log axis in matplotlib with labels of 10^-2, 10^-1, 10^0, 10^1, 10^2 etc

However, I would like 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100.

Could anyone guide me on this. I have tried a few options, such as:

```
ax.set_xticks([0.01,0.1,1,10,100])

ax.set_xlabels([0.01,0.1,1,10,100])
```

Any pro tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice way is to use the FuncFormatter class of the matplotlib.ticker module. In conjunction with a custom function definition of your own making, this can help to customise your ticks to the exact way you want them. This particular bit of code works well with the logarithmic scale employed by matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = np.linspace(-10,10)
y = np.exp(x)

plt.close('all')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(x,y,'bo')
ax.set_yscale('log')

#Placed the import/function definitions here to emphasize
#the working lines of code for this particular task.
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

def labeller(x, pos):
    """
    x is the tick value, pos is the position. These args are needed by 
    FuncFormatter.
    """

    if x < 1:
        return '0.'+'0'*(abs(int(np.log10(x)))-1)+\
                format(x/10**(np.floor(np.log10(x))),'.0f')
    else:
        return format(x,'.0f')

#FuncFormatter class instance defined from the function above
custom_formatter = FuncFormatter(labeller)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(custom_formatter)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think you want `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%g"))`, as in:

```
x=[0.1,1,10,100,1000]
y=[-1,0,1,2,3]
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y,'.-')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%g"))
```

Example output:
[image: example output from log plot axis label format change]

Answer (score 2):

First, instead of `set_xlabels` you should call `set_xticklabels` for the actual tick labels. That said, at least in my current environment (python 2.7, matplotlib 1.4.3, OS X 10.10) that is not always enough. When doing instruction by instruction in a REPL (e.g. ipython) sometimes is necessary to update the axis after calling `set_xticklabels`. A quick hack to do that is to simply call `grid(True)` or `grid(False)`. For example:

```
x = np.logspace(-2,2, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)

l = [0.01,0.1,1,10,100]

plt.semilogx(x,y)
plt.gca().set_xticks(l)
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(l)
plt.grid(True)
```

Empirical note: the `grid(False)` trick doesn't seem to be necessary when pasting that gist using ipython's `%paste` magic (anybody know why?)

Comment: Perfect, thank you ever so much. Awaiting to know further answers to your %paste caveat.